# Firing event on application close

Tags: c#

I have a winforms application that uses a network socket and I want to close the socket when the application is closed so how can I fire an event when the application is closed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the Application Event.
You can trigger an event on application close like this

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ApplicationExit +=new System.EventHandler(this.shutdownHandler);
```

Answer (score -2):

Make a handler for the 'FormClosing' event on your main window

Comment: This is when the form closes, not the application. The form closing does not mean the application is closing.