# Application closing event in C#

Tags: c#, .net, events

I'm writing a music player using NAudio. Before I close the player, I would like to call some methods that stop the playback. How do I do this?

Comment: WPF? Winforms? Something else?

Comment: It should automatically stop playing when the process exits.  If it does keep going then you have a threading problem in your code.  Look at the Thread.IsBackground property for a quick fix.  Debug + Break All to debug it.  AppDomain.ProcessExit is an event you're asking about.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firing event on application close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679829/firing-event-on-application-close)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**WinForms**

Subscribe to the [`Application.ApplicationExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit.aspx) event and in the event handler do your shutdown code.

**WPF**

Subscribe to the [`Application.Exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.exit.aspx) event and in the event handler do your shutdown code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `Form.closed` event would be good as well.

edit: only if you have one form

Comment: music players have only one form I guess and when I want to close it I simply close the window.

Comment: Bad assumption. What about configuration forms? About form? Don't assume.

Comment: In the programs that I wrote the user cannot switch to the main form so the other form will lose focus.

Comment: Is this an application that you have written?

Comment: Yes, just like that 
AboutDialog dlg = new AboutDialog();
dlg.ShowDialog(this);
dlg.Dispose();

Comment: I mean, is the application the OP is asking about one of the applications you have written? If not, how can you assume you know how it was coded?