# Handle Application.Exit(CancelEventArgs) in C#

Tags: c#, event-handling

Simply put, how can I subscribe to and handle the following event?

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit(new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs(true));
```

because apparently this is not going to give me my CancelEventArgs:

```
Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(ApplicationExitHandler);
private void ApplicationExitHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: The intent of this question is unclear.  Application.Exit() is canceled by any form who sets e.Cancel = true in its FormClosing event.

Comment: you want to cancel the Exit Operation. then try to use Form_closing event.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Still, what is the purpose of the CancelEventArgs in Application.Exit and how do you use it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firing event on application close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679829/firing-event-on-application-close)

Answer (score 1):

Try to put Event inside the **Form1.Designer.cs**

```
  private void InitializeComponent()
        {
          //.......... UI iniatilization

           System.Windows.Forms.Application.ApplicationExit +=new System.EventHandler(ApplicationExitHandler);

        }
```

In **Form1.cs**

```
 private void ApplicationExitHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //.............
        }
```